# RenderPage() with umlaut

Tags: c#, webmatrix, diacritics

I'm developping a webpage with WebMatrix C# (Razor). I have a _SiteLayout.cshtml containing the layout and everything, a index.cshtml with the start page content and a set of .cshtml files with additional information. These files are rendered with RenderPage("x.cshtml") into the index.cshtml file.

Now these files contain, as i'm from switzerland, "Umlaute" like ö, ä, ü. There is no problem writing Umlaute in the index.cshtml file, but the ones in the subfiles are not rendered correctly. They display like Ã¼ (ü). It would be a huge effort to rewrite the subfiles with html umlauts (ü), they are big and constantly changed by humans, which are not willing to convert every umlaut.

I think there is a problem with the html language settings, but I'm not sure. In the _SiteLayout.cshtml I specified `<html lang="de">`, but somehow it is not applied to the subfiles.

Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. Adding language specifications to the web.config file was helpful. I added the following to the system.web section:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" culture="de" uiCulture="de"/>
```

Thanks to Peter Stock for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Grüezi!
I'm not familiar with Razor, but it seems to be an encoding issue. I'd prefer to go for Unicode, because it covers all languages from Schwitzerdütsch to Suaheli.
[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/web-development-101-part-4-using-layout), I found this line:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Guete Morge, sadly it does not help. I tried `<meta lang="de"/>` `<meta name="language" content="de"/>`, too. No change... though it might be the right direction. Aber merci glich